# bash script adding users. setting the username to script argument

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, adduser

I'm trying to create a bash script that creates a new user.
I pass the desired username as a argument, but it's not accepting the value.

I'm trying to have:

```
root@forgehe:~# bash newuser.sh userexample
```

create a user named "userexample", but i get the error:

```
adduser: To avoid problems, the username should consist only of
letters, digits, underscores, periods, at signs and dashes, and not start with
a dash (as defined by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001). For compatibility with Samba
machine accounts $ is also supported at the end of the username
```

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DESIREDUSERNAME=$1
sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" $DESIREDUSERNAME
```

I'm very new to bash and linux, so I'll apologize in advance

Comment: What is "" supposed to do? I'd expect "$DESIREDUSERNAME" or $DESIREDUSERNAME

Comment: @Rinzwind I guess it's meant to populate an empty GECOS field - but it seems redundant

Comment: yes, steeldriver is correct